# Running out of memory, any methods to dynamically recycle unneeded nodes of a tree?

Tags: java, memory-management

I'm running an algorithm that generates a **huge** tree, the **least** runnable result came out with 2,069,073 nodes, and took up 3gigs of memory.

But that won't do!

My question is, are there any good methods or practices to dynamically recycle any unneeded nodes when running?

EDIT: "I'm running a multiprocessor scheduling algorithm with 2 machines and 10 jobs on each machine."

Comment: Perhaps look at moving to a tree that doesn't mind being on disk, such a B-tree?  Could you use the fly weight pattern to share values in the nodes?

Comment: You can buy servers much larger than this for a lot less than you used to. You can get a 16 GB PC for $1000. How much memory do you have?

Comment: Hey Lawrey, I'm a noob undergrad, plus I'm learning alot about these good practices. I'm running this program on a 4gig machine.

Comment: @Jeff, does implementing a B-tree require a lot of code change? If so, I'm afraid I'm forced to stick with my crappy tree due to the small window of time available.

Comment: A B-Tree would be a big change (well, it depends whether you're writing your own tree objects or using a package.  Maybe if you find an appropriate package to use it'll be easy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maintaining your own pool of nodes ... if that is what you mean ... won't help at all.  If the nodes become reachable, the garbage collector will find them.  A poorly implemented object pool can *stop* this happening, making the problem worse.

I suspect that your problem is that you are leaking objects.  If there are nodes in the tree that are no longer needed, you should be able to get rid of them by assigning null to the relevant field or array element of the parent node.  Assuming that your node graph is really a tree, that should be sufficient to disconnect the node and subnodes from the main tree, and (if it is now unreachable) make it eligible for garbage collection.

Another possibility is that there is another kind of memory leak somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

Please be more precise as what you need.

What means to "recycle"? As long as all those nodes are strongly
connected and not eligible for garbage collection, they will of course
not be GCed.

If any part of your tree is "disposable", i.e. no longer needed, you
should remove those connections and/or can use the existing objects to
link with other parts of the tree and fill with new data.

Comment: Your question also means, that your nodes are roughly 1,6 kByte big. Or do you have another memory leak?

Comment: What I mean is, I wish to free the memory of nodes that will not be used anymore.

Comment: That is correct, each node uses a minimum memory of 1384 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as there are no more reachable references to a given node it can be garbage collected. In rare cases it could make sense to trigger garbage collection manually like `System.gc()` but usually this is not necessary as GC happens periodically anyhow.

What do you consider unneeded nodes? If you will never visit/need them just remove if from the tree and let GC reclaim memory...

What kind of data do you store in each node? 3Gb seems alot to me...

Comment: I've never encountered such a huge amount of data, and that's why I'm lost. Each node has an ArrayList of children, and each child has a node pointing to the parent. If I use Peaches's method, is setting the parent pointer to `null` enough? Or do I need to remove the child from the ArrayList as well?

Comment: You definitely have to remove the parent->children pointer (parent pointer does not really matter).

Comment: (that is assuming you have a global pointer to the root.. in general: you have to ensure, that after removing a node from the tree there is no way to get a reference to the removed node anymore!)

Answer (score 1):

Well java is a Garbage Collected language, so this may not be necessary. [This website](http://www.interview-questions-java.com/java-questions/java-garbage-collection-interview-questions) has a very helpful explanation of Garbage Collection. According to the article, setting unneeded variables to `null` will allow them to be garbage collected.

Out of curiosity, what are you doing that generated 2 million nodes??

Comment: I see, thanks for your advice. I'm running a multiprocessor scheduling algorithm with 2 machines and 10 jobs on each machine. Is this normal? Or does my algorithm really suck...

Comment: It all depends on the data that you are passing. If they are just one byte chars then that is quite alot. But if you are putting Megabyte sized images into the tree, then you need more than a short answer =p